# How can I import date columns from excel without time

Tags: python, openpyxl, datetime-format

[Code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr8MY.png)
[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H4Ol.png)

I want to input date column form excel sheet but without time format

Tried to look for solutions they weren't specifically the ones I was looking for.

There are screenshots I uploaded for clarification

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do not post images of your code.

Comment: openpyxl seems to return datetime objects for cells which contain date information. You should be able to use d.strftime("%d/%m/%y") where d is your value for the date cell.

Comment: @GodIsOne Will remember that for future posts

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will help you. Try to follow these steps:

1. Open your Excel sheet and locate the column containing the date values.
2. Select the entire column by clicking on the column header.
3. Right-click on the selected column and choose "Format Cells" from the context menu.
4. In the "Format Cells" dialog box, navigate to the "Number" tab.
5. From the list of categories on the left, select "Date."
6. In the "Type" section on the right, choose a date format that does not include time values. For example, you can select "Short Date" or a custom date format that suits your preference.
7. Click "OK" to apply the formatting to the selected column.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).